# REST API with multiple Get methods

Tags: c#, rest, api

I am learning C# REST API implementation and i have a few questions about multiple Get methods.

Below is my sample code from NET Core 2.1 project

Questions:

1. Can i implement multiple Get methods in same controller?
2. Is my Configure code to MapRoute correct?
3. What URL should be to call  GetByName 
      (https://localhost:44306/api/Books/author=Smith) method?
4. is it normal to implement multiple GET,(POST) etc. methods in the same Controller

BooksController-----

```
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Book>> Get()
    {
        return _bookService.GetAll;
    }


    [Route("{name}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<Book> GetByName(string name)
    {
        var book = _bookService.GetByAuthor(name);

        if (book == null)
            return NotFound();

        return book;
    }
```

void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) ---

```
        app.UseMvc(routes => {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "author", template: 
           "api/{controller}/{GetByName}");
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You most certainly can have multiple gets on a single controller. It's quite common behaviour.

In your instance, to hit your GetByName you would need to call it with https://localhost:44306/api/Books/Smith, although I personally would recommend losing the route requirement and hit it by using https://localhost:44306/api/Books?name=Smith

E.G.

```
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<Book> GetByName(string name)
    {
        var book = _bookService.GetByAuthor(name);

        if (book == null)
            return NotFound();

        return book;
    }
```

It is perfectly normal to have multiple GETs on your controller. You would normally have one for listing, where you would call `youapi.com/api/Books` then maybe pass some filtering options in and expect a list in return. Then you can have a get individual, for example `yourapi.com/api?id=1234` that will return the single item that you highlighted.

The main thing to consider is that your controller should be unique to the entity. Create a new controller for a different entity (e.g. BooksController, AuthorController, PublisherController).

This is a great read on Restful Api design - https://link.medium.com/gBqAQPLT6Z

Comment: Out of interest,why the preference for the second querystring approach?

Comment: @MattEvans a very good question, one that I would have been asking myself not long back. I've recently had a shift in mindset and I like to be able to focus on keeping my endpoints from having property specifics embedded in the routes. I like to have a single GET for listing (with parameters for filtering) and another GET for individual items (by identifier) that are defined by the controller (in this case books).

In summary, it means that when I look at a list of all the controllers developed by the team, we will have the same build up of the urls with 2 GETS, a POST and a PUT TBC

Comment: And in a rare occasion, a PATCH. I find it easier for the entire team to stick to the same design and makes it easy for anyone to pick and use or call. For a more in-depth write up around the API Design in which I'm a big fan of, have a read here - https://link.medium.com/gBqAQPLT6Z

Answer (score 0):

> Can I implement multiple Get methods in same controller?

Yes. They just need to have unique routes. (There might be some more nuance to that rule, but it's the broad advice).

> Is my Configure code to MapRoute correct?

Doesn't look like it. `GetByName` is the name of the *method* not the route to the *action*. Actually the easiest thing to do is just not have any named routes at all in your Startup file:

```
app.UseMvc(); // that's it.
```

> What URL should be to call GetByName (https://localhost:44306/api/Books/author=Smith) method?

Assuming the full class looks like this:

```
[Route("api/Books")]
public class Books
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Book>> Get()

    [HttpGet("{name}")]
    public ActionResult<Book> GetByName([FromRoute] string name)   
}
```

Then to call the `Get` method you would call `/api/Books` and for the `GetByName` method you would call `/api/Books/abcd`.

> Is it normal to implement multiple GET,(POST) etc. methods in the same Controller?

Sure. Use controllers (in my opinion) to logically group similar endpoints by some criteria, usually by the resource type they interact with.

Comment: Thanks for Help, I tried last suggestion, but unfortunately /api/Books/abcd   or    /api/Books?name=abcd does not work for some reason. 
I think i am missing something small.